# Until and past tenses - are both correct or not?

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

I have a problem with these two sentences:

"You promised you would take care of her until she had grown up"

"You promised you would take care of her until she grew up"

Which of them is the correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid sentences, with a nearly identical meaning, especially in everyday practical use.  You haven't specified what your problem with these sentences is.  I guess that you might like to understand the slight technical difference in meaning?

The important difference is the inclusion of the word "had".

The sentence without "had" emphasizes that the promise is not fulfilled until the "grew up" event is reached ( by some measurement standard not included here).   That implies the promise persists until the milestone task of the very last step of that "grew up" process begins.

The sentence with "had" emphasizes that the promise is not fulfilled until  after EVERY task of the "grown up" process is completely finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is reported speech.

What was said:

Either:

I will take care of her until *she has grown up*.     (perfective aspect)

or

I will take care of her until she grows up.

Now, turn each of these into reported speech:

You said you would take care of her until she had grown up.

and

You said you would take care of her until she grew up.

So, both sentences are grammatical, but only one can be right because only one could have been said.

Answer (score -1):

I would choose no. 2 as the correct answer as it is technically and grammatically correct. The answer is clear and straight-forward.